# Unable to do teleop

Tags: a200, rostopic--pub, ros-electric, husky, ros-fuerte

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I am unable to move husky (even the teleop operation). The pc connected in husky has fuerte installed in it. When I try to run husky from my pc, which has electric in it, it isn't working.

The teleop works perfectly from the Husky PC.

When I try to run teleop after making Husky as my master, from my pc and move the joystick, then I am able to see the values in my PC through the following topic :-

> rostopic echo /husky/cmd_vel

But the husky is not moving.

I connected the joystick to the husky's pc and moved it, I was able to see those values from my PC.

I also tried to publish the cmd_vel manually using :-

> rostopic pub /husky/cmd_vel geometry_msgs/Twist -r 10 '[0.0,0.0,0.0]' '[0.0,0.0,1.0]'

Then it is getting published, but still husky is not moving.

Any help would be highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/42643/unable-to-do-teleop/) by [Arjun PE](https://answers.ros.org/users/2019/arjun-pe/) on ROS Answers with karma: 18 on 2012-08-30

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/195/ryan/) on 2012-08-30**:
Does running teleop from the Husky PC work?

**Comment by [Arjun PE](https://answers.ros.org/users/2019/arjun-pe/) on 2012-08-30**:
@Ryan Yes, it works from the Husky PC

**Comment by [Ryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/195/ryan/) on 2012-08-30**:
When you publish them from the joystick on the PC, try SSHing into the Husky PC and echoing /husky/cmd_vel there - this may be an Electric/Fuerte compatibility issue.

**Comment by [Arjun PE](https://answers.ros.org/users/2019/arjun-pe/) on 2012-08-30**:
I tried sshING, and it is working. Thank you for the idea. I think we should start a new thread for the compatibility issue. Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I suspect you have a networking issue here. While using electric and fuerte together is not supported and definitely not recommended, it should be fine in your case because the Twist message hasn't changed for years, i.e. it should still be compatible. Try the following:

- Start the teleop node on your PC.
- Log into husky and do a `rostopic info /husky/cmd_vel`. You'll see the name of the publishers and further down information about tcp/ip connections. Find out the node name that is publishing the topic.
- Execute `rosnode info <teleop node name you just found out` on husky. It will show you the host name of the publisher somewhere.
- Try pinging the hostname of the publisher on husky. If this does not work, you know it is a network problem because husky cannot subscribe to the topic published by your pc.

Now to fix it, have a look at [the networking troubleshooting page](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/NetworkSetup). I guess it will be sufficient if you set ROS_IP on your PC.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-08-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0